# How to use ChatGPT Standard Chat Module for Consistent Responses

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I would like to utilize the chat GPT gpt-3.5-turbo module as opposed to the text-davinci-003 module in order to engage in a conversation with the model, rather than receiving random responses. Could you please provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

Here is my existing code

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
require('dotenv').config()

const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.body);

    if(message.body.startsWith("#")) {
        runCompletion(message.body.substring(1)).then(result => message.reply(result));
    }
});

async function runCompletion (message) {
    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: message,
        max_tokens: 200,
    });
    return completion.data.choices[0].text;
}
```

I tried to change the model name into gpt-3.5-turbo but received the following error

`This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?`

I am uncertain about the appropriate approach to resolving this matter. Could someone kindly offer assistance, please?

I attempted to modify the model name to "GPT-3.5 Turbo," but encountered an error during the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use unsupported models

OpenAI has a list of supported models on their site.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility

For completions you can only use

```
text-davinci-003, text-davinci-002, text-curie-001, text-babbage-001, text-ada-001
```

The `prompt` can be an array of strings though.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-prompt

You might be able to get some continuity if you include the prompts from the user and the responses (similar to chat completions)